# replace a character in the string using DOS commands

Tags: command-line, batch-file, dos

I have a requirement in which I need to replace particular character from a string, by using a DOS command.

For example, if my string is "1,2,3,4", I need to get the result "1.2.3.4" by replacing each "," with a "." character.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following will work for you

```
    @echo off
    set string1=1,2,3,4
    set string2=%string1:,=.%
    echo %string2%
```

Answer (score 7):

This will give you an idea of what to do, not knowing exactly how you get the string to begin with.

```
set str=1,2,3,4
set str=%str:,=.%
```